# I had a problem solving nonlinear system of equations numerically in python

Tags: python, numeric

I'm currently trying to solve my fluid mechanics problem that results in three different equations by Python. After some research, I tried to make it as simple as I could, which resulted in the following code:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve 
import math

def equations(p):
    d, Re, f = p
    return (d**5 - 0.0165*f, 97200 - Re*d, f**(-0.5) + 2*math.log10(0.00015/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(Re*f**(0.5))))
 
d, Re, f =  fsolve(equations, (0.22, 0.0213, 490000))

print(equations((d, Re, f)))
```

Which gives a long error:

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-19-dcc7fc844bb6> in <module>()
>       6     return (d**5 - 0.0165*f, 97200 - Re*d, f**(-0.5) + 2*math.log10(0.00015/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(Re*f**(0.5))))
>       7 
> ----> 8 d, Re, f =  fsolve(equations, (0.22, 0.0213, 490000))
>       9 
>      10 print(equations((d, Re, f)))
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in
> fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev,
> band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
>     146                'diag': diag}
>     147 
> --> 148     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
>     149     if full_output:
>     150         x = res['x']
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in
> _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
>     225         with _MINPACK_LOCK:
>     226             retval = _minpack._hybrd(func, x0, args, 1, xtol, maxfev,
> --> 227                                      ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)
>     228     else:
>     229         _check_func('fsolve', 'fprime', Dfun, x0, args, n, (n, n))
> 
> <ipython-input-19-dcc7fc844bb6> in equations(p)
>       4 def equations(p):
>       5     d, Re, f = p
> ----> 6     return (d**5 - 0.0165*f, 97200 - Re*d, f**(-0.5) + 2*math.log10(0.00015/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(Re*f**(0.5))))
>       7 
>       8 d, Re, f =  fsolve(equations, (0.22, 0.0213, 490000))
> 
> ValueError: math domain error
```

Now, I understand that it must be related to log value, but I think the complexity of the equation also may play a role here.

Comment: It's because you are getting -ve value inside the log function, however I don;t have necessary domain knowledge to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `print(d, Re, f)` in your `equations(p)` function and see how the value changes over each iteration.

I did a run on it and these are the results before the error

```
0.22 0.0213 490000.0
0.22 0.0213 490000.0
0.22 0.0213 490000.0
0.22000000327825547 0.0213 490000.0
0.22 0.02130000031739473 490000.0
0.22 0.0213 490000.007301569
4384243.368454826 -464.7214227491007 3096116.988633934
```

As you can see, as it evaluates, the last row of values are actually invalid for the `f**(-0.5) + 2*math.log10(0.00015/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(Re*f**(0.5)))` operation since `0.00015/(3.7*d) + 2.51/(Re*f**(0.5))` evaluates to `-3.069524039032724e-06`, which is close to 0 and thus be recognized as 0. Therefore, since `log(0)` is invalid itself, it returns `Domain Error`

To fix this, you may want to revisit your formula or extend the number of significate figures to hold more number and stop it from being 0.